# Why is this python list showing empty in this certain case?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a text file using the csv module in which i have some values that is then extracted and two seperate lists are populated.

This is the example.txt file:

```
1,2
3,4
6,8
8,2
9,3
```

There are different outputs in different scenarios when i try to run this code:

```
with (open('A:\WorkSpace--Python\Plotter\MainSource\example.txt','r')) as egFile:
    plot=csv.reader(egFile,delimiter=',')
    x=[int(row[0]) for row in plots]
    y=[int(row[1]) for row in plots]
```

In ipython, when i reference x and y it outputs empty list for y.

For x:

> [1, 3, 6, 8, 9]

For y:

> []

But if i comment out the line where x is being populated, then referencing y returns the appropriate list.

```
with (open('A:\WorkSpace--Python\Plotter\MainSource\example.txt','r')) as egFile:
    plot=csv.reader(egFile,delimiter=',')
    '''x=[int(row[0]) for row in plots]'''
    y=[int(row[1]) for row in plots]
```

Output y:

> [2,4,8,2,3]

I have tried using different variable names , but the result remains same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `csv.reader` is a **lazy** (meaning it only produces data as needed) iterator that gets exhausted when you iterate through it once, like a generator. After declaring `x` it is empty.

You can materialise it with `list` to allow multiple iterations:

```
plot = list(plot)
```

However if your CSV file is large this will take a lot of memory, although it doesn't really make a difference in this case since you're saving all the values in `x` and `y` anyway.

An alternative would be:

```
x = []
y = []
for row in plot:
    x.append(int(row[0]))
    y.append(int(row[1]))
```

or

```
x = []
y = []
for xrow, yrow in plot:
    x.append(int(xrow))
    y.append(int(yrow))
```

Comment: What if i run the reader function multiple times?Would it still read from the same file? Or do i have to open in again?

Comment: @ashishkaran files are similarly exhausted by iteration, but you can `file.seek(0)` to reset them. However don't worry, just use `list` like initially suggested. I doubt your file is too big to handle in memory. If it is, you can't expect to plot it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @Alex, you can use an explicit loop for setting the x,y values:

```
x = []
y = []
with (open('E:\\TEMP\\xy.csv','r')) as egFile:
    plots=csv.reader(egFile,delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
print x
print y
```